# How can I stop Google Chrome from Autofilling form data on checkout?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, chrome-browser, autocomplete

The issue is only happening on Google Chrome. I need to stop Chrome from Autofilling the customers address. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I know it may seem weird, but if you add `autocomplete="nope"` to the input element, it may stop Chrome from trying to auto-fill it because "nope" is not actually a recognised auto-fill value. 
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

I've also seen talk of using `autocomplete="new-password"` instead, as that's a recognised implementation but Chrome won't try to auto-fill this. Be aware that some password manager extensions could see this and ask you to generate a secure password on the field (though I cannot confirm this)

Hope one of these helps!

*Disclaimer: I've not actually tested these properly before replying, so good luck.*